# Calendar View inside the app

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

Can any one suggest me how to show a calendar view inside my native app with all the events and whatever i wanted to add. Is there any framework provided in iOS 6?. The calendar view am looking for is it should be exactly as iCal(Day/Week/month) but inside the app.

Answer (score 1):

Check this open source library [Tapku](http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers). That should help in this case. You can also check with [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal).

You can also try to create one of your own. Basically you need to subclass a `UIView` and implement the `drawRect` method to draw it.